# Windows Event Forwarding between two computer out of a domain

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, certificate, event-log

I've got two computers and I want to set up event forwarding between them.
Source computer is out of a domain, another is in some Domain. I tried to configure source initiated event subscrption but it don't works or I don't know how to do that.
I know I have to use certificates, but how to get them (generate?). What certificates, where to store it? Please, help me if you know.

Answer (score 0):

[Setting up a source initiated subscription where the event sources are not in the same domain as the event collector computer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wec/setting-up-a-source-initiated-subscription#setting-up-a-source-initiated-subscription-where-the-event-sources-are-not-in-the-same-domain-as-the-event-collector-computer) from Microsoft Docs